# tcpdump doesn't capture DHCP Discovery

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dhcp, tcpdump

I tried to capture [DHCP Discovery](https://superuser.com/questions/811501/understanding-dhcp-discovery-specific-subnet?rq=1) through the [***`tcpdump`***](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html):

```
# ip l | grep enp5s0
3: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
# tcpdump -ni enp5s0
tcpdump: enp5s0: That device is not up
# ip l s dev enp5s0 up
# ip l | grep enp5s0
3: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
# tcpdump -ni enp5s0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp5s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

Then I do

```
# dhclient enp5s0 -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp5s0/2c:fd:a1:c6:d6:13
Sending on   LPF/enp5s0/2c:fd:a1:c6:d6:13
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPDISCOVER on enp5s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
...
```

But there is nothing in tab with tcpdump. What could be the problem?

P.S. the same behavior is with `ifup`/`ifdown`.